# Change Orientation of a WrapPanel in Wpf (mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a problem with the design of my WPF program. My XAML looks like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="{Binding Orientation}">
   <Border ... /> 
   <Border ... /> 
   <Border ... />
   <Border Margin="2"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           CornerRadius="3"
           Padding="4">
      <WrapPanel>
         <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="Time Range:"
                    Width="66" />
         <controls:WinFormsWrapper EndDateTime="{Binding EndDateTime,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                   InitialEndDateTime="{Binding InitialEndDateTime}"
                                   InitialStartDateTime="{Binding InitialStartDateTime}"
                                   StartDateTime="{Binding StartDateTime,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </WrapPanel>
   </Border>
   <Border ... /> 
</StackPanel>
```

Inside The WrapPanel you can see there is my WinFormsWrapper. In my Viewmodel i got a property `Orientation` which will determine how to Orientate the StackPanel. I want the WrapPanel now to fill the whole control horizontally if the Orientation is set to `vertical` and vice versa.

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

**EDIT:**

The Type of the property is `System.Windows.Controls.Orientation` and the possible values are: `System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical` and `System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal`.

Comment: a `StackPanel` is meant for the mentioned purpose. also tell us what is the type of `Orientation` property and what are the possible values?

Comment: @usre3596113 you can use trigger which binds to `StackPanel` Orientation property

Comment: @Fedor and what Attribute should i change to what value?

Comment: @user3596113 WrapPanel has `Orientation` property too.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a `Background` to your `WrapPanel` the panel is full size.
I think that you should use a `DockPanel` instead of your `WrapPanel` with the property value `LastChildFill="True"`.

Your error comes from invalid values. Set a valid start value to your `Orientation` property

```
private Orientation orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```